# Openshift data dir access in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, openshift

I've been trying to make my user uploaded date on OpenShift accessible publicly. However, I run into the issue that I can't seem to make it work in any way.

I'm using NodeJS to upload the files to process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR via express4 and fs.

The files upload just fine. However, I've read plenty of messages saying that I should link the folders together using "ln -sf ../route/to/app-root/data/folder linked_folder". Which I've done, but I cannot still access them publicly.

I honestly don't know what else should I do. Do the files automatically sync? Because that doesn't seem to be the case. Or should I be uploading to my repo folder and then OpenShift automatically links it to the data dir folder?

My current exact setup when doing "ln" is:

```
01| cd app-root/repo/public/
02| ln -sf ../../data/user-files user-files
```

Doing this to link the user-files folder in repo/public with the openshift data/user-files folder.

So the thing is that I can't access the files in the front end by doing "ln" at all. No clue where to go from here.

Comment: In my experience, changes made to `app-root/repo/public` during runtime don't show up in the app. I tried changing some Jade files and the changes didn't appear. Which made me believe it's not actually the live server. Also consider that when you update the repo and openshift reinstates the newer repo, would you re-create the link? I think it would be better to just dynamically set the "view" path in your code itself, just like you handled the uploads with `process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`.

Comment: @laggingreflex, yeah that's what I figured as well. However the problem is that the HTML is handled by AngularJS, and NodeJS is used just for the API. And of course the route passed by process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is not public.

Another solution I figured was on app initialize I could just copy the contents from data dir onto the repo. However, that might that a substantial amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need is:
1. store all your files in `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` directory
2. write a script that run before `server.js` or `app.js` it's function is to copy all data from `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` to your desired directory inside your repo like `public` directory or whatever you want.

SAMPLE: `initDataBeforeRun.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('./public', fs.readFileSync(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR));
```